# Latin form of Igor

Tags: vocabulary, names

How would you translate the name [Igor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igor_(given_name)) into Latin? The Latin Wikipedia uses *Inguarus* (e.g. [Inguarus Stravinskij](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inguarus_Stravinskij)), which is the Latinised version of [Ingvar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingvar_(name)).

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I'd go with *Inguarus* used by Wikipedia, since the name was basically Scandinavian and the form *Igor* represents a Slavicized version of that.  (I will admit, this is purely a matter of taste.)

Like Draconis, I can't find the name in any Latin sources, but (for what it's worth), it *does* appear in [Leo the Deacon's Byzantine historical work](https://books.google.com/books?id=GCMAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA3&dq=%22leonis+diaconi%22#v=onepage&q=%22leonis%20diaconi%22&f=false) as Ἴγγορ[ος] (Ingor), which looks like a Greek perception of the Scandinavian name.  (The context of the form ῎Ιγγορος seems to require a genitive, so I assume the nominative would be Ἴγγορ.)

But, ultimately, it's your choice.

Answer (score 3):

Mostly, it depends what you're using it for.

If someone named *Igor* travelled back to Ancient Rome, his name would probably be kept the same: *Igor* is valid Latin, and even looks like a standard agent noun (so it would probably be declined *Igor, Igoris, Igorī*…).

However, if, say, Rurik had decided to go to Rome instead of Kiev, then the name would have been transmitted from Old Norse as *Ingvar*. This might have gotten Latinized as *Ingvarus*, as Wikipedia did, or it might have been an indeclinable foreign noun, or it might have declined like *lar* (so *Ingvaris, Ingvarī*…).

For someone like Stravinsky, I would just borrow it as *Igor*. Unlike other names that have attested Latin predecessors (such as *Maria* for "Mary"), I don't know of any Latin sources which give a reliable form of this name. So it seems more reasonable to do what English does and just borrow it directly.

(P.S. I'd hoped that some of the old Slavic histories might have talked about Igor son of Rurik in Latin. Unfortunately, all the oldest sources I've found that mention Igor are written in Slavic languages instead of Latin, so they're not much help.)

(P.P.S. I write it *Ingvar* rather than *Inguar* because the *v* was a consonant in this context: compare *angvis* "snake", which is two syllables *an-gvis* rather than three **an-gu-is*. Basically, after *n*, *gv* was a labialized consonant like *qv* rather than a consonant and a vowel.)